Unable to access .NET 8 API from container instace
I have created a .NET 8 web API and deployed in a container instace.
When I try to access the application, I am unable to access from container instace.

Docker file
*FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Net8/Net8.csproj", "Net8/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./Net8/Net8.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Net8"
RUN dotnet build "./Net8.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build
FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./Net8.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish
/p:UseAppHost=false
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Net8.dll"]*
Is there any limitation with .NET?

There is no limitation in .NET, but you can create Docker container without any exposed ports or remap port.
To simplify working with Docker containers you can use .NET Aspire

Have you tried deploying .NET 8 api in container instance and able to access.

Yes. Twice or more per day.

Can you provide your docker file sample and container instace settings? I am facing issues

@BalanjaneyuluK https://pastebin.com/6SmnETLK

I am still unable to access the deployed application

I am able to deploy and access. Thanks for the details.
